# Swift: Tableview and Search Bar send null object on first time with segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, segue

I have a tableview with a search bar. Search methods are okay, work well. I have a problem with **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** part.

When I select an list item (cell), need to pass this item to next scene with an segue.

But when I select an cell to show item details;

**first selection:** null object,
**second selection:** first object,
**third selection:** second object pass to next scene.

**My vehicle class:**

```
class Vehicle {
    var owner : String 
    var plate : String 
    var location : String 
    var isOnline : String 
    var state : String 
    var speed : String 
    var driver : String 
    var maxSpeed : String
    var dailyOverSpeed : String 
    var energy : String 
    var firstEngineDate : String 
    var messageDate : String 
    var dailyKm : String 
    var totalMoving : String 
    var totalWaiting : String 
    var totalParking : String 
    var totalKm : String 


    init() {
        self.owner = ""
        self.plate = ""
        self.location = ""
        self.isOnline = ""
        self.state = ""
        self.speed = ""
        self.driver = ""
        self.maxSpeed = ""
        self.dailyOverSpeed = ""
        self.energy = ""
        self.firstEngineDate = ""
        self.messageDate = ""
        self.dailyKm = ""
        self.totalMoving = ""
        self.totalWaiting = ""
        self.totalParking = ""
        self.totalKm = ""
    }

    init(owner: String, plate: String, location: String, isOnline: String, state: String, speed: String, driver: String, maxSpeed: String, dailyOverSpeed: String, energy: String, firstEngineDate: String, messageDate: String, dailyKm: String, totalMoving: String, totalWaiting: String, totalParking: String, totalKm: String) {
        self.owner = owner
        self.plate = plate
        self.location = location
        self.isOnline = isOnline
        self.state = state
        self.speed = speed
        self.driver = driver
        self.maxSpeed = maxSpeed
        self.dailyOverSpeed = dailyOverSpeed
        self.energy = energy
        self.firstEngineDate = firstEngineDate
        self.messageDate = messageDate
        self.dailyKm = dailyKm
        self.totalMoving = totalMoving
        self.totalWaiting = totalWaiting
        self.totalParking = totalParking
        self.totalKm = totalKm
    }
}
```

**My tableview controller:**

```
class VehiclesTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate{
...
    var vehicles = [Vehicle]()
    var filteredVehicles = [Vehicle]()
    var selectedVehicle = Vehicle()
.....
}
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath** :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if (tableView == self.tableView) {
            self.selectedVehicle = vehicles[indexPath.row]
        } else {

            self.selectedVehicle = filteredVehicles[indexPath.row]
        }


        println(self.selectedVehicle.plate)

    }
```

**prepareForSegue** :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "DisplayViewSegue" {
            var nextScene  =  segue.destinationViewController as! DisplayViewController
            nextScene.currentVehicle = self.selectedVehicle


        }
    }
```

When I select any cell (with search or without search) my println() works corrent which is in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Confused?

Comment: How did you bind these 2 controllers in UIStoryboard?

Comment: Making segue (show) with Xcode which named **DisplayViewSegue**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have the searchbar as the top element of the tableview, so that when you acces an element from your vehicle array it needs to be indexPath.row-1. Also if you only segue when you select a row your can access the index directly with self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow() and use that to get the proper vehicle hope this fixes your problem